# Creating an eBook with GIF animations

Tags: pdf, publishing, file-format

I run a technical blog and publish articles regularly that have GIF animations. Examples: [one](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/packet-traveling/host-to-host-through-a-switch/#switch-operation) [two](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/packet-traveling/osi-model/#encap-decap) [three](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vlans/#extending-vlans).

I plan to aggregate a bunch of these articles into an eBook of sorts. I know I could break out the animations into individual, still images, but I think the fact that they are animated make them much more conducive to learning and involving for the reader.

As far as I know, a typical PDF does not allow for a GIF animation. If not for a PDF, what options do I have for a published eBook that also allow for these animations?

Comment: Do they have to stay as animated GIFs? Or could you convert them to a different format that is more easily included in a popular eBook format?

Comment: @BrandonHaugen What other format would allow an animation / video in a PDF?

Comment: PDF supports a variety of video formats, depending on what the intended audience is going to view the files with these may be an option. Adobe provides a list of what is supported by Acrobat : https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/playing-video-audio-multimedia-formats.html

Comment: EPUB 3.0 supports a variety of video formats as well that might suit your needs. I am not sure if EPUB reading applications are better or worse at supporting video than PDF viewing applications : http://epubzone.org/news/multimedia-support-in-epub-3

Comment: @BrandonHaugen Interesting, didn't know about video support in PDFs. Thanks for the link.  Regarding EPUB, how portable is that?  I would hate to have to troubleshoot case by case when customers purchase EPUB, versus the general ubiquitous support for PDF files.

Comment: The nice thing about the EPUB ecosystem is that they manage a site that tests conformance to the spec wth various EPUB reading applications where you can see the results (http://www.epubtest.org/testsuite/epub3/). I don't think anything like this exists for PDF viewing applications, I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

We can integrate the gif format in epub3 packages say as a background to div container or another option would be convert gif to mp4 format.

Comment: Sorry to just now see this answer. Could you elaborate, Leon? Yes, the GIFs can be converted to MP4 (they started as MP4, actually).